# Eigenvalues of strange matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a rather weird square matrix, $M_n$, that is of dimension $n$. That's the best I can explain it, I think. It has a general form, and I think it's best to just show some examples

$$
M_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 2 & -2\\
1 & -2 & 3
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
M_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
-1 & 2 & -2 & 2\\
1 & -2 & 3 & -3\\
-1 & 2 & -3 & 4
\end{pmatrix},
$$

$$
M_5 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
-1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -2\\
1 & -2 & 3 & -3 & 3\\
-1 & 2 & -3 & 4 & -4\\
1 & -2 & 3 & -4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

As you can see in each column/row the sign changes for each element, and for the $i^{th}$ row/column, the $i^{th}$ to the $n^{th}$ elements all have norm $i$. I don't know if it's any use explaining it further, as the form becomes pretty clear from the examples given. My question is, has anyone seen something like this and does anyone know if there's a way of calculating the eigenvalues?

Comment: The matrix whose entries are $(M_n)_{i,j} = (-1)^{i+j}\min\{i,j\}$ is unitarily similar to the matrix whose entries are $(A_n)_{i,j} = \min\{i,j\}$. There are some results about that matrix in [this paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/spma/open-issue/article-10.1515-spma-2016-0010/article-10.1515-spma-2016-0010.xml).

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial.  This is irreducible over the rationals in many cases ($n =  1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 29, 30, \ldots$), so in general I think there is no simple formula for them.  The characteristic polynomials (call them $C_n(\lambda)$) appear to satisfy the recurrence

$$  C_{n+2}(\lambda) = (2\lambda-1) C_{n+1}(\lambda) - \lambda^2 C_n(\lambda)$$
with $C_1(\lambda) = \lambda - 1$, $C_2(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - 3 \lambda + 1$.

$1$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $n \equiv 1 \mod 3$.